# String index problem on my sudoku solver program

Tags: python, string, list, sudoku

This is my code for a sudoku solver and I am getting this error:

```
  File "c:/Users/Documents/untitled-17.py", line 85, in <module>
    if board[i][j] == 0:
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

My code is below and I am unsure of the error and how to fix it. I am not sure if the error is because of the main function or the solveBoard function. I am also unsure if this is the only error I will run into after I fix this one error. I am afraid that if I fix this one error I might screw up my whole program. This is the import file I am reading from, only difference is there is no extra new line in between the numbers. Here is the file:

9 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 6 3 1 0 0 0 0 5

4 0 0 6 5 0 0 7 2

0 7 0 9 6 0 0 2 3

2 0 9 0 0 0 1 0 6

3 4 0 0 1 5 0 8 0

1 9 0 0 2 7 0 0 8

6 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 1

```
def main():
    L = []
    fileName = input('Enter input file name: ')
    inFile = open(fileName,'r')
    print('Initial Game')
    
    line = 9
    for x in range(line):
        a = inFile.readline()
        first = a.split()
        H = first
        H = (str(H).replace("'",""))
        L.append(H)
    x = (str(L).replace("'",""))
    y = x.replace("],", "],\n")
    return y

myBoard = main()
 
def isValid(board, row, col, num):
 
    #check row
    for i in range(9):
        if board[row][i] == num:
            return False
 
    #check col
    for i in range(9):
        if board[i][col] == num:
            return False
 
    #get top-left corner
    c_row = row - row%3
    c_col = col - col%3
 
    #check 3x3 square
    for i in range(c_row, c_row+3):
        for j in range(c_col, c_col+3):
            if board[i][j] == num:
                return False
 
    #return True if none of the cases above returns False
    return True

 
def solveBoard(board):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                for num in range(1,10):
                    if isValid(board, i, j, num):
                        board[i][j] = num
                        result = solveBoard(board)
                        if result == True:
                            return True
                        else:
                            board[i][j] = 0
                return False
    return True
 
 
 
solveBoard(myBoard)

for line in myBoard:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the file it is reading from?

Answer (score 0):

```
#check col
    for i in range(9):
```

should be
for j in range(9):

Answer (score 0):

Running this code, it looks like the `board` array being passed to `solveBoard()` is  269 x 1 and you're treating it like it's 9 x 9

I can't check without the full input file, but I think the following is likely to fix your file input parsing:

```py
def parse_board_file(filepath):
    board = []
    with open(filepath, 'r') as input_file:
        print('Initial Game')
        row = []
        for line in input_file:
            for character in line:
                if character.isdigit():
                    row.append(str(character))
                    if len(row) == 9:
                        board.append(row)
                        row = []
                    if len(board) == 9:
                        return board
    # if you make it to here, you reached the end of the file before
    # finding enough numbers
    print("ERROR: a full 9x9 grid could not be parsed from the given file.")
    return board
 
def isValid(board, row, col, num):
    # ...rest of function...
 
def solveBoard(board):
    # ...rest of function...

def main():
    filepath = input('Enter input file name: ')
    board = parse_board_file(filepath)
    solveBoard(board)
    for line in board:
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

However, with the given test case this still did not succeed in completing the board. Sudoku requires iteratively filling in the next cell that has been narrowed down, so it would be **very very** unusual for only one pass over the board from top to bottom to be able to solve each square. But even wrapping your code in an extra loop to run until the board is solved likely won't help here.

The following datapoints may help you refine your approach:

1. The condition to fill in a cell in your code is just that there is no reason that number cannot go there. However, when just starting out more cells will be blank than not, so lots of cells will be able to be filled with this logic. Once some have been filled in, you may find there are no valid moves remaining so some of the earlier moves may have been in error. This is because the condition you are looking for in Sudoku is not "can this number go here?" but in fact "does this number **have to** go here?" and "is this the **only** number that can go here?" The cell should remain blank until there is **only one option** that fits it.
2. Harder sudoku do not rely only on knowing which numbers are already present in a row, column or square. They may rely on conditions such as if the places a certain number can go has been refined to one of a few options that are all in a certain place. e.g.

```
1 2 3               7 8 
4 5 6     7 8 9     1 2 
7 8 9     1 2 3     4 5 

Square A  Square B  Square C
```

In this scenario, there are 3 cells remaining in Square C and if you only considered rows and squares then a 6 could go in either the top or bottom of those cells. **However**, even though the 6 has not been placed in Square B, we can still know that it will have to be placed in the top row. Therefore, the 6 would need to go in the bottom empty cell in Square C.

I hope this sets you on your way to a solution :)